# Validating Winners

Tags: php, algorithm

I`m managing an online trading game system.
I require the following fields upon registration:

- Email
- Username
- Password
- Sex
- Phone Number
- Name and Surname

And the users IP upon registration.

The point is that I imposed to written Terms and Conditions on the site:
One user can have 2 usernames under the same IP, everything which finds itself outside this condition will be disqualified.
So two users having thus 4 usernames registered under the same IP are prone to fraud.

My problem is:
How do I uniquely identify each user.

I cannot use the IP, because there can be multiple users behind a router or worse use Mobile GPRS, etc.

I cannot use a social identification number, cause they might gather all of their relatives and use their social number.

Emails, everyone can set an email pretty easy.

I`m running out of ideas.

Later Edit: I could enforce a security key, generate one for each user subscribed, with that key, the user can later add another user, on a different IP.

I know It will probably not be as secure, but it will certainly make it harder

Comment: You can make them pinky-swear.

Comment: You say your T&C prohibits multiple users under the same IP, then two sentences later say you can't validate by IP. Which is it?

Comment: @Nick Johnson: My T&C more correctly states that users can have exactly 2 usernames, they can be or not under the same IP, but two users can not be under the same IP or else it`s dubious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use their phone number, and require them to receive a registration text. They could still use a friend's phone, but it would be a lot less prone to abuse.

Is there a cash prize involved? If so, there's probably nothing you can do to completely prevent abuse.

Comment: Later Edit: I could enforce a security key, generate one for each user subscribed, with that key, the user can later add another user, on a different IP.

I know It will probably not be as secure, but it will certainly make it harder

Comment: In that case you're going to have to employ some pretty sophisticated abuse detection. I would definitely start with the phone thing, but then set up some way to detect one person signing into multiple accounts, or pairs of accounts that only trade with each other. You'll really have to put yourself in your users' shoes and try to think of everything they could do to exploit the system, and close those vulnerabilities.

Comment: @gabriel really you can never totally stop cheating. It is going to happen and all you can do is revoke the prizes and ban users if you catch them. That said most people are honest, but you can't run on honesty alone. @Chriszuma is probably right about the phone things. You can still cheat on them but they are easily the hardest thing to cheat and validating accounts via phone is becoming more common place as Google, Facebook and I think PayPal are doing such things.